# sending a table from ajax to Django Rest framework

Tags: ajax, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to send a JS table to a Django Rest API View and read that parameter in the *get_queryset()* function

Here's my ajax call :

```
$.ajax({
   type       : "GET",
   url        : fetchDataUrl,
   data       : {
     table : [10,20,30,40,50],
   },
   success    : function(data){

   },
   error      : function(data){

   }
});
```

Here's my APIView :

```
class LivreListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class    = BookSerializer

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        table        = self.request.GET.get("table",None)
        ...
```

Comment: and what is your issue?

Comment: I can't get the table, a None is returned

Comment: can you show the result url generated by your ajax code? and add the question to your post.

Answer (score 0):

self.request.GET is a QueryDict object so it can be casted to a python dict by calling

```
data = dict(self.request.GET)
#under python 3
```

and then we can access tables by adding *[]* after the table name

ex:

```
#In my case
data = dict(queryDict)
table = data.get('table[]')
```

UPDATE:

A better way is to use *getlist()*
so :

```
table = self.request.GET.getlist('table[]')
```